# Magento 2 custom column sorting not working

Tags: magento2, xml

I have created custom column in `Sales -> Order` **UI Grid**. I have added **"Profit"** column. Which is not related to any database table and not the attribute. This column display just calculation of profit.

The issue is I can not sort the column. Column is sortable but it is sorting incorrectly.

I have checked many similar question in stack but nothing helpfull. As the column is not in table and not the attribute.

Following is my override file.

**sales_order_grid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="total_paid" class="Company\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PurchasedPrice">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Profit</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">13</item>
                </item>
            </argument>

        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: Please check my answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61119974/4073812) post. Hope it may help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is already old question, but it can be helpful for someone like me facing this issue.

According to this [Magento 2 GitHub issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4620) there is a `ui_bookmark` table in which some settings about ui_components (and Grid in my case) are stored.

Truncating this table and clearing the cache in my case fixed the problem of columns sortOrder in Grid.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem and below link helped me to get through it. Please follow the link provided below to add sorting and filtering of custom column in grid:

[Custom Column Sorting in Admin Grid - Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149445/custom-column-sorting-in-admin-grid-magento-2)

Comment: Thanks but as I mentioned the column is not in any table. The data of the column is coming from on block where I calculate the profit and return the profit amount. So this link is not useful.

Comment: @DavidCoder Did you ever find an answer to your question ?