# Magento2 Need to filter grid when value is entered in search box, the column of the data is from another table

Tags: magento2, layout, collection, grid

I have added 4 columns in the grid as displayed in below screenshot.

[image]

For displaying for eg. Recipient Email column I added following code in XML & it's renderer PHP file. (Code is added below)

app/code/Company/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_giftcardaccount_block.xml

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Recipient Email</argument>
                        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">recipient_email</argument>
                        <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Recipientemail</argument>
                        <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
```

app/code/Company/Module//Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/Recipientemail.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer;
class Recipientemail extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,      
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item $orderItem,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;      
        $this->orderitem =  $orderItem;  
    }


    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $code = $row->getCode();
        $result = array();
        $salesorderitem =  $this->orderitem->getCollection()
                          ->addFieldToFilter('product_options', array('like' => '%'.$code.'%'));

        if(!empty($salesorderitem)) 
        {
            foreach($salesorderitem as $orderdata){
                $productOptions = $orderdata->getProductOptions();   
                $recipientemail = $productOptions['giftcard_recipient_email'];
                if(!empty($recipientemail)){
                return $recipientemail;
                }else{
                    return '-';
                }
            }
        }else{
               return '-';
        }


    }
```

**Main table of grid is - magento_giftcardaccount**

**Recipientemail table is - product_options**

```
{"info_buyRequest":{"uenc":"aHR0cDovLzE5Mi4xNjguMS4xODQvZGcvZHJ1bW1vbmQtZ29sZi1lLWdpZnQtY2FyZC5odG1s","product":"76450","selected_configurable_option":"","related_product":"","giftcard_amount":"5","giftcard_sender_name":"test","giftcard_sender_email":"testmscgoriteeps@gmail.com","giftcard_recipient_name":"test22","giftcard_recipient_email":"arjun.cmarix@gmail.com","giftcard_message":"test test gift","qty":"1"},"giftcard_sender_name":"test","giftcard_sender_email":"testmscgoriteeps@gmail.com","giftcard_recipient_name":"test22","giftcard_recipient_email":"arjun.cmarix@gmail.com","giftcard_message":"test test gift","giftcard_lifetime":null,"giftcard_is_redeemable":0,"giftcard_email_template":null,"giftcard_type":"0","email_sent":0,"giftcard_created_codes":["HQE9EMUNTA6N"]}
```

My issue is the filter is not working. When I enter email in the search text field of grid it keeps on spinning for some time & grid is loaded as it is without filter.

It would be really appreciable if someone can guide me on how to filter this search text.

Comment: how you make your grid using UI or block?

Comment: Using block & render

Comment: can you please share the code of your block in which you call the collection for grid

Comment: @abdus added code in my question

Comment: You can view my friend's answer and take reference from there and apply as per your requirement.. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149445/custom-column-sorting-in-admin-grid-magento-2 Feel free to comment if you face any issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one, I got a similar case and found a solution, using the _initSelect in the collection and changing the index in the xml. Just follow the steps and you will be fine!

First you need to add a preference for the collection and overwrite **_initSelect()**:

```
<preference for="Magento\GiftCardAccount\Model\ResourceModel\Giftcardaccount\Collection" type="Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Giftcardaccount\Collection"/>
```

Inside the collection **Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Giftcardaccount\Collection** extend the select to add the required table with a wildcard in the select:

```
class Collection extends \Magento\GiftCardAccount\Model\ResourceModel\Giftcardaccount\Collection
{
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['sales_order_item' => $this->getTable('sales_order_item')],
            'sales_order_item.product_options like CONCAT("%",main_table.code,"%")',
            ['sales_order_item.product_options']
        );

        return $this;
    }
}
```

For performance I suggest you change your file:
**app/code/Company/Module//Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/Recipientemail.php**

```
class Recipientemail extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json
     */
    private $serializer;

    /**
     * Recipientemail constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json|null $serializer
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context,
        array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row) {
        if (empty($row->getProductOptions())) {
            return "-";
        }
        $productOptions = $this->serializer->unserialize($row->getProductOptions());
        $recipientemail = $productOptions['giftcard_recipient_email'];
        if(!empty($recipientemail)){
            return $recipientemail;
        }else{
            return '-';
        }
    }
}
```

Finally you need to change the **adminhtml_giftcardaccount_block.xml** file, this in order to take the filter:

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.logging.archive.grid.columnSet.recipient_email" as="recipient_email">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Recipient Email</argument>
        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">sales_order_item.product_options</argument>
        <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">WolfSellers\CatalogRule\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Recipientemail</argument>
        <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

I tested in my local environment, it works!

Comment: Can you let me know what should I do for sorting? Also, as I am having too much data so it just keeps on loading.

Comment: Just FYI, it is filtering entire 'sales_order_item.product_options' & not only 'giftcard_recipient_email'.

Comment: @Arjun Yes it will filter all the product_options, the thing is in the collection filter must be done by sql, and since mysql does not unserialize, this is the best solution so far, otherwise it will be a really pain in the ass to load everything, on the other hand, sortable must be done with some other tricks. My suggestion, do not sort it, search instead

Answer (score 0):

You can join 2 or more table in **`_initSelect()`** function of collection class **`Test\TestModule\Model\ResourceModel\Gift\Collection`**. After Joining the table you can use join tables column in your grid.

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();

    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(['secondTable' => $this->getTable('your_table_name')], "secondTable.entity_id = main_table.entity_id ", ['secondTable.value as alies_name']);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Will this work on 'product_options' column in sales_order_item'

Comment: yes, you can join any table

Comment: I have added product_options data in my question. I need to get 'giftcard_recipient_email' data

Comment: I want to join product_options table value with other table value

Comment: please update your question with all related code and clear requirement

Comment: I added this question which makes more sense https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/282069/magento2-join-query

Answer (score 0):

You can Get Data From Multiple Tables using _initSelect Function in `Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Gift\Collection`

```
 protected function _initSelect()
        {
            parent::_initSelect();
            $secondTable=$this->getTable('product_options');
            $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(' ".$secondTable.",' ".$secondTable.".entity_id = main_table.entity_id ', [' ".$secondTable.".giftcard_recipient_email as Recipent Email]');
        }
```