# magento2 join query

Tags: magento2, query, join

I want to join the main table code with the `product_options` value `giftcard_created_codes`

My query till now

```
$this->getSelect()->joinLeft(['secondTable' => $this->getTable('sales_order_item')], "secondTable.product_options = main_table.code ", ['secondTable.product_options as product_options']);
```

`product_options` value

```
{"info_buyRequest":{"uenc":"aHR0cDovLzE5Mi4xNjguMS4xODQvZGcvZHJ1bW1vbmQtZ29sZi1lLWdpZnQtY2FyZC5odG1s","product":"76450","selected_configurable_option":"","related_product":"","giftcard_amount":"5","giftcard_sender_name":"test","giftcard_sender_email":"testmscgoriteeps@gmail.com","giftcard_recipient_name":"test22","giftcard_recipient_email":"arjun.cmarix@gmail.com","giftcard_message":"test test gift","qty":"1"},"giftcard_sender_name":"test","giftcard_sender_email":"testmscgoriteeps@gmail.com","giftcard_recipient_name":"test22","giftcard_recipient_email":"arjun.cmarix@gmail.com","giftcard_message":"test test gift","giftcard_lifetime":null,"giftcard_is_redeemable":0,"giftcard_email_template":null,"giftcard_type":"0","email_sent":0,"giftcard_created_codes":["HQE9EMUNTA6N"]}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: please add structure of your main_table

Comment: Added in my question you can verify

Comment: i have posted the solution, please accept and upvote if it solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.

```
$this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('sales_order_item')],
    new \Zend_Db_Expr("JSON_UNQUOTE(json_extract(secondTable.product_options, '$.giftcard_created_codes[0]')) = main_table.code"),
    ['secondTable.product_options as product_options']);
```

Comment: I got error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: missed semi colon in second argument, edited the answer.

Comment: i used your code but it keeps on continuous loading

Comment: Can you please print the query and paste the sql here ? also execute that sql in your mysql and check if you get appropriate data or not ?

Comment: By the way what do you want from sales_order_item ? i dont understand your requirement ...

Comment: SELECT `main_table`.*, `secondTable`.`product_options` FROM `magento_giftcardaccount` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `sales_order_item` AS `secondTable` ON JSON_UNQUOTE(json_extract(secondTable.product_options, '$.giftcard_created_codes[0]')) = main_table.code

Comment: I need to get values where main_table.code = product_options giftcard_created_codes value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96204/discussion-between-yash-shah-and-arjun).

Answer (score 0):

```
$subquery = new \Zend_Db_Expr("select json_extract(product_options, '$.giftcard_created_codes') from sales_order_item");
$this->getSelect()->join(['sq' => $subquery], "main_table.code = sq.value", []);
```

Comment: I got error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: i have updated my answer check now

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: please check now

Comment: Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Comment: print query and see what is the problem