# Sorting custom column in ui component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, custom, sorting

I've created a custom column in the report using UI components that use DataProvider in report_listing.xml
Unfortunately, this new custom column is not able to sort.

I made also a class for this column which extended Column class Ui\Component\Listing\Column\testColumn::applySorting() to change sorting but this method is only using existing columns from sales_order.
I'm only able to sort via existing in sales_order columns.

```
protected function applySorting()
    {
        $sorting = $this->getContext()->getRequestParam('sorting');
        $isSortable = $this->getData('config/sortable');

        if ($isSortable !== false
            && !empty($sorting['field'])
            && !empty($sorting['direction'])
            && $sorting['field'] === $this->getName()
        ) {
            $this->getContext()->getDataProvider()->addOrder(
                'custom_column',
                strtoupper($sorting['direction'])
            );
        }
    }
```

If there is no possibility to somehow made it like that, maybe I can kinda set values for a new column in another way to make possible sorting.

Comment: please share your xml code so I will check it quickly and easy to for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the link provided below to add sorting and filtering of custom column in grid:

[Custom Column Sorting in Admin Grid - Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149445/custom-column-sorting-in-admin-grid-magento-2)